# Library for stock options calculations

Tags: c++, stocks, financial

I am writing some financial analysis software and need to do some calculations concerning stock options.  I need to calculate the current value of a short position if it were closed by selling, by getting exercised, or by expiration.  However, I do not have a good method to test if my calculations are accurate.  Ideally, I would have a C++ library that could do these calculations for me.  But, I am willing to use practically any language MATLAB, C++, Perl, R, Java, c#, etc to build a unit test against my code.

Does anyone know of a good financial analysis library?

Comment: If you have a lot of money, [FINCAD](http://www.fincad.com/) seems to be the industry standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you check out if [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) can help you.

Comment: Oh wow!  This is way better than I expected, but my head is spinning with all the different types of options.  For starters I just want to sell American put stock options.  Can you recommend which class(es) to use?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've known about QuantLib for a long time, but I've never been involved in a project where I could actually use it. Why don't you try out its mailing lists?

Comment: This library looks like a dream come true for what I am doing.  I hope google picks up this post and gets people using it and improving it.  Thank you so much!!!!